# I want to access old value as well as current value from Behavior Subject

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a scenario where in one of the components sends a value via form and i need to pass it to another component, so I have used Behavior Subject via a shared service as I thought it will be the best way to achieve what I need.

service.ts
   `private Type$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null); getType(): Observable<any> { return this.Type$.asObservable(); } emitType(type: any | null): void { this.emitType$.next(type); }`

component.ts where i am emitting

````
  ``` save(){
    .......
    this.service.emitType(_data.Type!);
   }```
````

component.ts where i am using
`ngOninit(){ this.service.getType().subscribe((type: any)=>{ this.Type = type console.log('types', this.Type); }) }`

I found out behavior subject takes in only the last value, so i used ReplaySubject, now on console.log I can see that multiple values are fetched over my screen but still at the end type has last value. I need different type values to do different stuff

Comment: You have access to the old values via ReplaySubject. There are pipe operators like `scan` if you need to accumulate older and newer values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pairwise()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/pairwise#description) to emit the current and previous values as an array, so when you subscribe, you'll get both:

```
private Type$ = new Subject<any>();

getType(): Observable<any[]> { 
  return this.Type$.pipe(
    startWith(undefined),
    pairwise(),
    shareReplay(1),
  ); 
}

emitType(type: any | null): void { 
  this.Type$.next(type);
}
```

Since `pairwise()` will not emit until it receives 2 emissions, we use [`startWith`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/startWith) to feed it an initial `undefined` value. To achieve the multicast and replay functionality that `BehaviorSubject` has, we can add [`shareReply(1)`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/shareReplay).

Then, in your component:

```
ngOnInit() { 
  this.service.getType().subscribe(
    ([previous, current]) => { 
      this.Type = ...; 
      console.log('types', { previous, current}); 
    }
  ) 
}
```

---

Note, it's not beneficial to wrap observables in functions (*unless you are passing arguments needed to define it*).  Observables are lazy and nothing will happen until it is subscribed.  Instead of creating a `getType()` method and returning observable, you can simply define a property that is an observable:

```
private _Type$ = new Subject<any>();

public type$: Observable<any[]> = this._Type$.pipe(
  startWith(undefined),
  pairwise(),
  shareReplay(1),
); 

emitType(type: any | null): void { 
  this._Type$.next(type);
}
```

Then, in your component:

```
ngOnInit() { 
  this.service.type$.subscribe(
    ([previous, current]) => { 
      this.Type = ...; 
      console.log('types', { previous, current}); 
    }
  ) 
}
```

Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-75083274?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftype.service.ts) you can play with.